# Extrude with Proportional Editing

Tags: modeling

I didn't find a way to combine the two tools, extrude and Proportional Editing.
Is it possible?
My goal would be to model something like basalt columns easily...

Comment: Afaik Extrude, along with Slide tools aren't affected by Proportional Editing; you should cancel extruding and then proceed to PE.

Comment: Any idea if this might be added in a future version of Blender?

Comment: The fact that these tools aren't affected sometimes helps very much, it lets you slide verts/edges without turning off PE etc. I don't know anything about adding that in future; it should be convenient to cancel extruding just after executing it and using PE as you wish after that. You might want to show what you're trying to achieve by editing your post; probably the solution is easy.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly, but extrude works like this: when you press <kbd>E</kbd>, blender

- creates new connected geometry
- immediately enters "grab" mode (but not using Proportional)

If you cancel(<kbd>ESC</kbd> or right click), you cancel only the last "grab" action, thus leaving the new geometry where it was before entering the "grab mode", and still selected.

You could issue this as a bug or a feature request, though, imho.

So, you can just enter "grab mode" again (eg pressing <kbd>G</kbd>) but now your enabled Proportional Editing will work

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't reproduce that (or at least what I understood)... Maybe it doesn't work the same on a Mac... I'll have to find something else...